# Python3 : How to handle xml contain binary string when convert to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml-to-json

I'm in a scenario that get XML data from the file and parse it into Dictionary but inside the XML data is contain some value like binary

> "%¢a÷ó<·RxgÐ¢'gÎ&"

then I got the error :

> parser.Parse(xml_input, True) xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: reference
> to invalid character number: line 4032, column 15

Here is my sample python code:

```
import xmltodict
with open(myFile, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as fd:
   doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
```